# PhoneGap and JQuery mobile issue loading the page (yet another "Access-Control-Allow-Origin")

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have the following code using PhoneGap and JQuery Mobile:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test RSS</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var onDeviceReady = function() {
        ... //some code

        $("#homePage").live("pageinit", function() {

            ... //some more code

        });
    };

    function init() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
    }
</script>

</head>
<body onload="init();" id="stage" class="theme">

<div data-role="page" id="homePage">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1></h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="linkList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h6>Market Bytes by @toddysm</h6>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="contentPage">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#homePage" data-rel="back">Home</a>
        <h1></h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" id="entryText"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

For some reason though I see the following error when $("#homePage").live("pageinit", function() is executed:
    *XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1:44104/[some-GUID]. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin*
The thing is that I am not trying to load a separate page and the suggestions I found so far don't work.

Any ideas what the solution is?

Comment: Did you managed to solve this? I also get these errors in logcat although they don't seem to be causing any malfunction in my application.

Comment: No, I haven't solved it. The problem still exists on my side :(

Comment: I think we've hit some Phonegap bug. I'm using version 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Just searched in Cordova issue tracker and it seems that it is solved in version 2.1.0: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1101

EDIT: I've built and tested [cordova version 2.1.0](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-android/zipball/2.1.0), and I don't get those messages anymore. To build it, download the zip file and follow the steps in the README.md file, but instead of running this command: `android update project -p . -t android-15`, you need to specify android-16, so the command is: `android update project -p . -t android-16`.

Comment: PhoneGap 2.1 was released a few days ago, maybe now you can try, a see if that solves your issue too.